# how to format tables in Mails / outlook

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, model-view-controller

I am sending email using Spring MVC but It is showing differently In Browser and outlook email

```
    @Service("emailService")
    public class EmailService {  
    @Autowired
     private JavaMailSender mailSender;
     StringBuilder ResponseTable=new StringBuilder();
       public void sendMail(String emailid,String subject,int 
         tracking_id,String classification_type){


      MimeMessage message=mailSender.createMimeMessage();
      MimeMessageHelper helper=new MimeMessageHelper(message,true,"UTF- 8");    

     helper.setTo(emailid);
     helper.setText(ResponseTable.toString(),true);

     helper.setSubject(subject);

     mailSender.send(message);


   }
  }
```

[image: when i am open browser email]

[image: when I open outlook]

Comment: please re-tag you question. This question is hardly related to any of these tags. It is basically related to "how to format tables in Mails / outlook".

Comment: With just 2 screenshots this question is impossible to answer. Add the code that is preparing and sending the email, your configuration etc. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a velocity Engine Template to create a custom template :

1. create your template mailTemplate.vm
2. create a methode where you can insert you data in a model
3. create a methode to insert this model in your template

   1.mailTemplate.vm

   ```
   <html> 
   <head></head>
   <body>
       <p>hello,</p>
       <p>${variable}</p>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   2. Create Model to send the Notification Mail

      ```
       public Boolean NotificationMail(String sender, String receiver, String url,
                String subject,String footer) {

              LOG.info(" ... Sending new Subscription Notification Mail ");
              try {
                JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
                mailSender.setHost(mailHost);
                mailSender.setPort(port);
                mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(setMailProperties());

                Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                model.put("variable", "hello this is the text will be display in the mail");


                String body = getVelocityTemplate(model);
                LOG.info("Mail host {} , Port {} , url {} , sender {}  , receiver {} , subject {} , body {} ",
                    mailHost, port, url, sender, receiver, subject, body);
                Boolean sent = mailService.sendMailWithImg(sender, receiver, subject, body);
                return true;
              } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                LOG.error("IllegalArgumentException , Missing configuration", e);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("General Exception :{}", e);
              }
              return false;
            }
      ```
   3. insert model in the Template

      ```
       protected String getVelocityTemplateContent(Map<String, Object> model) {
      StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      builder.append("/template/mailTemplate.vm");
      try {
        VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplate(velocityEngine, builder.toString(), "UTF8", model,
            stringWriter);
        return stringWriter.toString();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error",e);
      }
      return null;
          }
          }
      ```